# Retrieve tr from table

Tags: jquery

How can i retrieve all the tr with class="ccc" from a table with id"=iii"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the direct child selector will be faster:

```
$("table#iii>tbody>tr.ccc");
```

Also, there is no point in `table#iiii`. An id selector is faster than an element selector, so the following will suffice:

```
$("#iii>tbody>tr.ccc");
```

In fact, if you can add an ID to your row (e.g. `MyRow`) then you can bypass this alltogether, cutting down considerably the amount of DOM traversing you have to do

```
$("#MyRow");
```

Comment: Adding the same ID to each row would cause a W3C validation error, every ID should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
var rows = $('table#iii tr.ccc');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table#iii tr.ccc")
```